# "match hardware" in dhcpd.conf not working

Tags: mac-address, isc-dhcp, dhcpd

I've been trying to get mac addresses with a certain OUI into a certain address pool.  I haven't been able to get it to work at all.  Here is a snippet of my dhcpd.conf and how it's applied.

```
class "testphones" {
        match hardware;
}
subclass "testphones" 1:00:07:3b:cb:c9:cf; 

class "avaya-9630" {
   match if substring(hardware,1,3) = "00:07:3b"; 
}

subnet 172.18.16.0 netmask 255.255.248.000 {
    option subnet-mask 255.255.248.000;
    option broadcast-address 172.18.23.255;
    option routers  172.18.16.1;
    option avaya-242 "OPTIONS"

    pool {
        range  172.18.18.1  172.18.23.254;
        deny members of "testphones";
        deny members of "avaya-9630";
    }

}

subnet 10.X.128.0 netmask 255.255.248.000 {
    option subnet-mask 255.255.248.000;
    option broadcast-address 10.X.135.255;
    option routers  10.X.128.5;
    option avaya-242 "OPTIONS";
    pool {
            range  10.X.129.1  10.X.134.255;
            allow members of "testphones";
            allow members of "avaya-9630";
    }
}
```

I don't get any of the mac addresses to match the "avaya-9630" class.  They all get handed IPs from the first (172.18.16.0/21) subnet.  The "testphone" does work, though.  It goes into the 10.X subnet.

Why does the "testphone" class work but not the "avaya-9630" class?

One thing that might cause a problem is I'm using a petty old version of ISC DHCP (3.0.1).  I don't know if the syntax is different for that older version.  The man pages seem to indicate I'm doing it right.

I've tried various iterations of the "match" line.  I tested with the following:

```
match if substring(hardware,1,3) = "1:00:07:3b";
match if substring(hardware,0,3) = "1:00:07:3b";
match if substring(hardware,1,4) = "1:00:07:3b";
```

None worked.

Your thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It works without the quotation mark.
For example, in this case:

```
match if substring(hardware,1,3) = 00:07:3b;
```

This way, it works in my production environment.

Comment: Please give a working example of what you mean.

Comment: Sure. Example added.